# Text selection does not move on scrolling iScroll in iOS application

Tags: javascript, css, objective-c, iscroll

In ios application, I have implemented simple iScoll Demo in UIWebView.

Now when I select text, and scroll, the selection remains at same position on the screen
and text move up with scrolling.

In below screenshot, I have selected text, and scrolled up, the selection remains at same place on screen and text moves upwards.

Refer Screenshot.

[image]

Is there any solution for this, so that selection moves along with text?

You can fine my sample project here https://github.com/vaibhavsilar/helloworld.git